# Rewiring two switches from fan and lights to two separate light fixtures

Tags: wiring, switch, light, fans

I took out two fan/light combos and replaced them with two light fixtures (sans fans). The switch box had two switches - one that controlled both lights, one for both fans.

How do I rewire the switch box so that each of the new lights is connected to its own switch?

[image]

Comment: At a minimum, we'll need pictures of the boxes in the ceiling and how the wires get there from the switches.

Comment: Yes, can you get us photos of the insides of the ceiling boxes please?

Comment: With the breaker off , From what I see on the fan switch if red pull those off the switch and cap them then move one of the lights to the other switch  I would do the work at the wire nut where the 3 reds or blacks combine , or if the red is the fan at that wire nut remove the red wire from the bundle and put the nut back on the 2 reds. Now at the black wire nut pull the wires out there is 1 black going to the switch connect with one of the blacks or directly to the switch if long enough. Now you need 1 additional wire nut to connect the remaining black to the red. This should work if on 1 bkr